# How do I add conditional flow in apigee with else condition?

Tags: apigee

I have a flow in which I have added a condition which says

```
<Flow name="getuserdata">
    <Response>
        <Step>
            <FaultRules/>
            <Name>GetUserData</Name>
        </Step>
    </Response>
    <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath &quot;/idm/user&quot;) and (request.verb = &quot;GET&quot;) and (request.header.stub = "true")</Condition>
    <Request/>
</Flow>
```

So what's happening here is when the condition matches `true`, it goes to the Javascript `GetUserData`, but what I want to do is when the condition false it should go to another service callout flow named as `GetUserDataFromServer`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no "else" construct available. You need to add another condition which is exact logical opposite of the if condition.

This poses two challenges:

1. Code maintainability. You need to maintain the condition effectively twice.
2. Each condition is evaluated during the execution (that is two times in stead of one)

As an alternate, if you have the 'if / else block' inside a python, javascript or java callout policy this two challenges are overcome.

However much of the logic gets hidden from the XML proxy file and gets inside the supporting resource files. Makes it less readable by a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a flow without a condition at the end - it would be executed if nothing else matches. This like `default` case in `switch` statement.